# how to call Pig scripts from shell script sequentially

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-pig

I have squence of Pig scripts in a file and I want to execute it from Shell script 
which execute pig scripts sqeuenciatly.

For Ex:

sh script.sh /it/provider/file_name   PIGddl.txt

Suppose PIGddl.txt has Pig scripts like

1. Record Count
2. Null validation e.t.c

If all the Pig queries are in one file then how to execute the pig scripts from Shell scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below idea works ,but if you want sequential process like if 1 execute then execute 2 else execute 3 kind  of flow,you may go with Oozie for running and scheduling the jobs.

```
#!/bin/sh
x=1
while [ $x -le 3 ]
 do

echo "pig_dcnt$x.pig will be  run"

pig  -f /home/Scripts/PigScripts/pig_dcnt$x.pig --param timestamp=$timestamp1

x=$(( $x + 1 ))

done
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I'm pretty sure this will work fine.

Lets assume you have two pig files which you want to run using shell script then you would write a shell script file with following:

```
#!/bin/bash

pig

exec pig_script_file1.pig

exec pig_script_file2.pig
```

so when you run this shell script, initially it will execute `pig` command and goes into `grunt shell` and there it will execute your pig files in the order that you have mentioned

### Update:

> The above solution doesn't work. Please refer the below one which is
>   tested

Update your script file with the following so that it can run your pig files in the order that you have defined

```
#!/bin/bash

pig pig_script_file1.pig

pig pig_script_file2.pig
```

Comment: I used exec command in shell script but its just entering into grunt shell and not executing the the pig scripts.

Comment: This should run pig scripts from shell script....

    #!/bin/bash

    pig pig_script_file1.pig

    #OR

    pig -x mapreduce pig_script_file2.pig

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do 
1. Keep xxx.pig file at some location #
2. to execute this pig script from shell use the below command 
pig -p xx=date(if you have some arguments to pass) -p xyz=value(if there is another arguments to be passed) -f /path/xxx.pig
-f is used to execute the pig lines of code from .pig file.